# How to increase performance with cross join and LIKE and NOT LIKE operator?

Tags: sql, oracle, query-optimization

I am using below query to using join condition, it takes more time to run and cost of query also getting higher.
I dont have any clue to replace any operator.
Can any one suggest for best query to perform well

```
select column1 as start_1, column2 as end_2
from table1 a cross join table2 b
where a.key = b.id
and (b.id_number LIKE '%123%')
and (a.tye IN (203, 201))
and (b.process_typ not LIKE '%G%');
```

Comment: Can you post the table definitions, index definitions, and query plan?  It is probably unlikely that much can be done with predicates that include leading and trailing wildcards.  Depending on what the data actually looks like, you might be able to use Oracle Text to tokenize the strings but that looks unlikely just based on the column names.

Comment: This is not a cross join, it is an inner join, because of the `WHERE` clause.  There isn't much you can do to optimize this query, as you have `LIKE` logic with wildcards on both sides (not sargable).

Comment: Also, negative predicates (e.g. NOT LIKE; NOT IN; !=) tend to discourage the optimizer from using indexes. There are many things working against this query, unfortunately.

Answer (score 0):

Although it won't affect performance, write the query using `JOIN`/`ON`:

```
select column1 as start_1, column2 as end_2
from table1 a join
     table2 b
     on a.key = b.id
where b.id_number LIKE '%123%' and
      a.tye IN (203, 201) and
      b.process_typ not LIKE '%G%';
```

You want indexes on the tables.  Unfortunately, `LIKE` with wildcards at the beginning of the search pattern prevent the use of indexes.  But you can use:

- `table1(tye, key)`
- `table2(id)`

You probably already have the second index, assuming that `id` is the primary key of the table.

If you need string searches, you *might* find Oracle's full text search capabilities useful.  Alternatively, there might be computed columns that can help with the query.  For instance, if "123" or "G" actually mean something, then perhaps you should put this information as flags rather than parsing strings.

Comment: Could the `LIKE '%G%'` be rewritten as `INSTR( process_typ, 'G' ) > 0` and a function-based indexed be created for that? That would be very specific to the predicate, though.

Comment: @eaolson . . . Yes.  However, I would probably use `(case when process_type like '%G%' then 1 else 0 end)`.  However, a binary flag usually does not make for a good index.